# How to assign AWS EventBridge with 1 rule but 2 targets in cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-event-bridge

I am very new to cloudformation and I am trying to implement a single rule with the same S3 bucket source, but has 2 different Lambda's as targets.

```
customEventBus:
    Type: AWS::Events::EventBus
    Properties:
      Name: "customEventBusName"

  eventRule:
    Type: AWS::Events::Rule
    Properties:
      Name: eventRuleName
      EventBusName: !Ref customEventBus
      EventPattern:
        source:
            - "aws.s3"
        detail-type:
          - 'Object Created'
        detail:
          bucket:
             name:
               - test-bucket
      State: "ENABLED"
      Targets:
        - Arn: !GetAtt lambdaA.Arn
          Id: "eventRule"
        - Arn: !GetAtt lambdaB.Arn
          Id: "eventRule"
```

I have set 2 lambdaA and lambdaB as targets but this will fail. Can someone help me please. Thank you.

S3 (new file added) -> Eventbridge (1 event bus with 1 rule) -> Run LambdaA and LambdaB (2 targets)

Comment: The Id should be unique for each target.

Comment: As @BhaveshParvatkar, the target IDs have to be unique. For example, for lambdaA, rename the ID as "eventRule-A" and "eventRule-B" for lambdaB.